# Postgres Unaware data FK (feat JPA)

Tags: postgresql, jpa

```
    @Builder
    @Getter
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "Calendar")
    @IdClass(CalendarPK.class)
    public class Calendar {
    
        @Id
        private int year;
        
        @Id
        private int month;
        
        @Id
        private int day;
        
        @MapsId
        @OneToMany
        @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "year"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "month"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "day"),
        })
        List<CalendarData> CalendarDataList;
        
    }
```

```
    @Builder
    @Getter
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Entity
    @EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
    @IdClass(CalendarDataPK.class)
    @SequenceGenerator(
        name = "CALENDAR_DATA_GENERATOR",
        sequenceName = "CALENDAR_DATA_SEQUENCE",
        initialValue = 1,
        allocationSize = 1)
    @Table(name = "CalendarData")
    public class CalendarData {
    
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "CALENDAR_DATA_SEQUENCE")
        private long seq; 
    
        @Id
        private int year;
        
        @Id
        private int month;
        
        @Id
        private int day;
    
        private long userId;
    
    }
```

```
    @Getter
    public class CalendarDataPK extends CalendarPK {
        
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private long seq;
    }
```

```
    @EqualsAndHashCode
    public class CalendarPK implements Serializable {
        
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        
        private int year;
        private int month;
        private int day;
    }
```

I create this code and testing ( PG ADMIN )

insert into calendars(year,month,day) values(2021,2,10); -> Success

insert into calendar_data (year,month,day,seq) values(2021,2,10,1); -> fail

**ERROR LOG
DETAIL: (year, month, day)= (2021, 2, 10) key does not exist in the "calendar" table.**

What is the problem???

below JPA made DDL

```
------------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE public.calendar_data
(
    seq bigint NOT NULL,
    day integer NOT NULL,
    month integer NOT NULL,
    year integer NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT calendar_data_pkey PRIMARY KEY (seq),
    CONSTRAINT fkfl96et9e3y700rv08r7rq9wfu FOREIGN KEY (month, year, day)
        REFERENCES public.calendars (month, day, year) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.calendar_data

---------------------

CREATE TABLE public.calendars
(
    day integer NOT NULL,
    month integer NOT NULL,
    year integer NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT calendars_pkey PRIMARY KEY (day, month, year)
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.calendars
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it ..

Just I need **referencedColumnName**

```
@JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "year",referencedColumnName = "year"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "month",referencedColumnName = "month"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "day",referencedColumnName = "day")
    })
```

I think column location is the cause

below hibernate log ...

AS-IS

```
Hibernate: create table calendar (day int4 not null, month int4 not null, year int4 not null, 
primary key (day, month, year))
...
Hibernate: alter table if exists calendar_data add constraint FKd5kpvvc1pj0r9rifkqnf89ui9 
foreign key (year, month, day) references calendar
```

TO-BE(add referencedColumnName)

```
Hibernate: create table calendar (day int4 not null, month int4 not null, year int4 not null, 
primary key (day, month, year))
...
Hibernate: alter table if exists calendar_data add constraint FKd5kpvvc1pj0r9rifkqnf89ui9 
foreign key (day, month, year) references calendar
```